# How to include hooks in CMS pages?

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've created a custom hook, so that I can include my custom module in any .tpl file by a single line: `{hook h='calcSubstrate'}`.

However, I can't use it in CMS page, at least not by using the admin panel - including smarty code in a CMS page won't render, the code would appear just as it is, as a text: {hook h='calcSubstrate'}.

Alternatively, if that would be easier/faster - how can I choose on which pages my module would appear?

Comment: Are you sure in admin panel Smarty is also used? If it were Smarty, there should be info that modifier is not recognized by default (but probably that behaviour could be also changed).

Comment: Well, that is what my question is about - does admin panel render Smarty code? and if yes - how? or if not - what other way can we include hooks in chosen articles/pages?

Comment: Where you put this code - in HTML file or in TPL file? If in HTML file, it's probably pure HTML not Smarty so obviously it won't work. If admin panel doesn't use Smarty, you won't be able to use hooks.

Comment: Neither of those. By CMS pages I don't mean any files - I mean articles with content you edit in admin panel, so I guess they are stored in database. Back to the point, if admin panel is useless for adding hooks to chosen articles, what may be the other way?

Comment: You will have to implement your own solution by overriding CmsController class. I would create something like shortcode mechanism which is used in Wordpress, which replaces shortcode tags with defined content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editor for CMS page won't recognize any Smarty code. To include hooks in chosen articles/pages, I can think of two options:

- Include the hook in the template (`cms.tpl`), and check for the id of the current page to conditionally display the module. The list of the page ids can be made as the module's configuration.
- Build a module to add functionality similar to Wordpress's shortcode to the CMS content. I do this with module instead of overriding the `CmsController` class, hence I have to display the content with `{$cms->content|module}`. You can look at the simplified code here for inspiration: https://gist.github.com/tungd/cef0ca1ac1063c1ee90b. Of course you can make it more generic like Wordpress, by having only one Smarty modifier `do_shortcode` that does everything (just like [Wordpress's `do_shortcode` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L190)).

Last time I did this it was because my client want to put slideshows in some CMS pages, and I chose the second approach because it gives a lot of flexibility about when the module is displayed and where it is displayed between the content. For something else, for example Contact Form, or Map, this would be overkill and the first approach is better.